# MASM/NASM Differences

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm

What are the syntax differences between the NASM and MASM assemblers?

Comment: Related: [How to know if an assembly code has particular syntax (emu8086, NASM, TASM, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853636) shows some syntax diff examples.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Section 2.2 of the NASM documentation is titled [Quick Start for MASM Users](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2) which lists the important differences between NASM and MASM.

NASM version 2.15 added some MASM compatibility, including a `%use masm` macro package.  See [section 6.5 `masm`: MASM compatibility](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5).  Even without the macro package, `?` and `DUP` work in data directives like `db`, and `displacement[base+index]` is allowed instead of the usual `[rdi+4]` syntax which NASM used to require.

Also related, *[How to know if an assembly code has particular syntax (emu8086, NASM, TASM, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853636/how-to-know-if-an-assembly-code-has-particular-syntax-emu8086-nasm-tasm)* discusses some of the syntax differences.

Comment: in that section is stated: "NASM Is Case-Sensitive"  
However, MASM also can be case-sensitive, simply use:
option casemap :none

Answer (score -3):

What an interesting question. The difference between them is, they are not compatible! But then again, nasm assemblers are not compatible amongst themselves, it seems. Learned it the hard way, while compiling libvpx. I think this single example says it all:

ml64.exe (MSVC 2019) -> throws

nasm for windows -> compiles some *.asm files, throws on some

```
invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Huh?

yasm for windows -> works

llvm assembler (debian) -> throws:

```
    /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/llvm-as
```

https://packages.debian.org/experimental/llvm-13

yasm (debian) -> works

nasm (debian) -> works

GNU assembler -> ???

https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/binutils-common/as.1.en.html

Comment: GAS / llvm-as in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode use syntax that's pretty much MASM for instructions, but with directives that are specific to them.

Comment: `nasm -felf64 foo.asm` should work the same way no matter what host you're building on.  If you have some asm files that assemble on Linux but not Windows, it's probably because of building with different bitness (e.g. `nasm -fwin32` vs. `nasm -felf64`), or something about directives, or possibly the .asm uses `%if` conditional stuff an does something different on Windows.)  Without an example of the instructions, it's not useful to say that NASM on windows errors.  What, on every file in general?  No, of course not.