# Countdown Timer in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to make a game in Assembly and I need to have the user enter something within a time period (Ex: 10 seconds). I cannot find anything online on how to implement something like this in MASM. Maybe I'm just searching wrong but it seems like everything I find is in NASM.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MASM/NASM Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035747/masm-nasm-differences)

Comment: MASM and NASM are just minor syntactic variations of the same language. It's easy to mechanically convert one to the other.

Comment: What OS/Platform are you targeting?

Comment: Like Chris said, what target?  The likely options for MASM are Windows (WinAPI system calls via DLLs), or DOS, or freestanding bootloader (legacy BIOS or UEFI).